# Linear transformation and Exact sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, exact-sequence

> Let V be a vector space over the field F, and W $\subset$ V a subspace. Then the linear transformation T: V $\rightarrow$ V / W is well-defined, since v $\in$ [v].

I understand v $\in$ [v], but how v $\in$ [v] implies T is well-defined? To my knowledge, being well-defined means that there is only one possible value for each T(v).

> Supopse A, B and C are three vector spaces. Furthermore, assume the sequence $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ is exact. Then, ker($B\rightarrow C)=A$.

By the definition of the exact sequence, ker($B\rightarrow C)$=im($A\rightarrow B)$. Could you explain why ker($B\rightarrow C)=A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two separate questions.

1) $T$ implicitly sends $v$ to $[v]$. $[v]$ is unique: it describes a single member of $V/W$. Therefore $T$ is well-defined, since it sends $v$ to a unique $T(v) = [v]$.

2) Technically saying $\ker(B\to C) = A$ is a bit inaccurate, since the kernel must be part of $B$, not $A$. However, note that the short exact sequence implies that the map $A \to B$ is injective; therefore, $A$ is isomorphic to the image of $A \to B$ in $B$ (let's call this image $I$). As you noted, $I$ is the kernel of $B \to C$. Therefore, $A$ is *isomorphic* to the kernel of $B \to C$.

Comment: Thank you! Since the map $B\rightarrow C$ is surjective, is C isomorphic with B / A?

Comment: Yes (or at least with $B/I$... technically the notation $B/A$ won't have any meaning if $A \not\subset B$, but you'll see that kind of notation used anyway)